# Is it possible to send clubbed data to google analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am newbie to GA.

Recently I got a weird requirement from one of my clients, he wants me to send clubbed data (a table row) to GA, where he can perform group by on particular attribute.

I have managed to track screen views, crashes, overall usage of app. But not getting how to push a table row to GA? I have also tried custom dimensions and custom metrics but the result is not what I want..

Am I thinking in wrong direction or is there any API to achieve this?

Any pointers will be appreciable.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by clubbed data.  But the only way to uploaded data directly is via https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads

Comment: @DaImTo by clubbed data I meant.. say I have a table `foo` with `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` as columns. Whenever data entry is made in this table, the entire row should get reflected to GA... I went through the `Uploads`, I wonder is it available for android?

Comment: Probably not but you could put in a feature request.  I am not sure if the android sdk is open source or not

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use event tracking, I sometimes push some urls or jsons so I can track specific user events... See if this helps:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/events